# how to open many webpages at once from terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, firefox, brave, vivaldi

Before upgrading to 20.04, I routinely opened batches of websites by copy/pasting from a spreadsheet full of URLs into a terminal. For example:

```
firefox nytimes.com &
firefox google.com &
```

Each site would load in a new tab. (In an existing window if firefox was already open.)

This now fails. For firefox, vivaldi, brave...

If Firefox is already running, this error message pops up:

*"Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile."*

(...where it did not before. New tabs used to appear in my existing session.)

Why? Fix?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Can you give us some more details?

Comment: What actually happens, vs. what you're expecting to have happen?

Comment: plz forgive, @ThomasWard

Will fetch error...

Comment: "This now fails" : what is happening instead? Should still work as you indicate, even without the need of the ampersand for subsequent invocations.

Comment: For Vivaldi You run it like this: `vivaldi --new-tab https://google.com --new-tab https://bing.com`